# When closing an CloseableHttpClient do I also have to close the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: httpclient

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
connManager.setMaxTotal(120);
connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
   
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setConnectionManager(connManager)
    .build();
```

Is it enough to close the httpClient or do I also have to explicitly close the connectionManager?

```
httpClient.close(); // Is this enough?
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the mean time. AbstractHttpClient seems to shut down the connection manager. So I think it should be ok to just close the httpclient.

See org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient

```
@Override
public void close() {
    getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```